# Search analytics from the Google Search Console shows weird peaks of impressions

Tags: google, google-search-console, impressions, search-analytics

My web site impressions on certain dates peaks as below. What could be the reason, I tried many things but I still cannot figure out. The web site is food related web site and the 9K impressions would make more sense. However daily impressions are limited to 900 currently.

[image: Web site performance from google analytics]

Comment: Use the report to see if those impressions have a fingerprint. e.g. all from one country. Specific queries, low positions etc.